# Update ID if Sequence MAX_VALUE reached

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I am using the following TRIGGER to Insert in my TEST Table:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TRG_CYCLE 
BEFORE INSERT ON TEST_CYCLE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :NEW.LOGID IS NULL
  THEN SELECT SEQ_CYCLE.nextval INTO :NEW.LOGID from dual;
 END IF;
END;
```

SEQ_CYCLE is the Sequence. Now I have to use the CYCLE option in order to start with 1 after the MAX_VALUE is reached. Since I don't want duplicate LOGIDs I want to do an UPDATE if the LOGID exists, if not an INSERT. Can I do this inside the Trigger?

Comment: So your requirement is to overwrite random rows in your table? Fascinating.

Comment: You are asking if you can, the question is whether or not you should do this, and the answer is no.  Simply provide a high number limit on the sequence and you'll never have to worry about duplicates.  Also, with 12C, you can specify a sequence as a default value for a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you may need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger; to build such a trigger you need to create a VIEW over your table and build the trigger on this view.

For example, say you have:

```
create sequence SEQ_CYCLE maxValue 3 cycle nocache;
create table TEST_CYCLE ( logId number, someColumn varchar2(20));
```

You can create a view and a trigger over the view:

```
create or replace view v_test_cycle as select * from test_cycle;

create or replace trigger trgCycle
instead of insert on v_test_cycle
for each row 
declare
    vCheck number;
    vSeqVal number := SEQ_CYCLE.nextVal;
begin
    select count(*)
    into vCheck
    from v_test_cycle
    where logId = vSeqVal;
    --
    if vCheck = 0 then
        insert into test_cycle(logId, someColumn) values ( vSeqVal, :NEW.someColumn);
    else
        update test_cycle
        set someColumn = :NEW.someColumn
        where logId = vSeqVal;
    end if;
end;
```

If you do the INSERTs on the view, this is what you get:

```
SQL> select * from test_cycle;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into v_test_cycle(someColumn) values('some value 1');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into v_test_cycle(someColumn) values('some value 2');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into v_test_cycle(someColumn) values('some value 3');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into v_test_cycle(someColumn) values('some value 4');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into v_test_cycle(someColumn) values('some value 5');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_cycle;

     LOGID SOMECOLUMN
---------- --------------------
         1 some value 4
         2 some value 5
         3 some value 3

SQL>
```